# Solving for 4 unknowns with 2 linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Actually, I was working on a physics problem, but the question which I had was a kind of math question. So, I encountered the following problem. While solving the Schrodinger equation for some potential and using the boundary conditions for the solutions such that I had 2 equations which 4 unknowns $A,B,k$ and $q$-
$$A+B=Ae^{i(k-q)L}+Be^{-i(k+q)L}$$
$$ik(A-B)-ik(Ae^{i(k-q)L}-Be^{-i(k+q)L})=\frac{g_0}{L}(A+B)$$
where $g_0$ and $L$ are constants.

Now, is there any way to solve these equations for some family of solutions? Also, why would that method work? Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to solve the first for $A$ to get
$$
A = B \frac{e^{-i(k+q)L}-1}{1-e^{-i(k-q)L}}
$$
and plug that into the second one...

Comment: So, does that mean A and B are free variables? As in, can they take any value?

Comment: @Tachyon209 this means $A$ is not free since it depends on the other three, and the second equation can be used to solve for $B$ after plugging in. Then $k$ and $q$ will be free and the two equations will determine $A$ and $B$

Comment: So, if I want to solve for k and q, then A and B have to be free?

Comment: @Tachyon209 another possibility is that $B$ will cancel from both sides after plugging in (seems likely right now) so $B$ will be free and whatever remains of (2) will have to be solved for $k$ or $q$...

Comment: @Tachyon209 yes, but offhand that seems like a more difficult problem

Comment: Yeah. That was exactly what I was thinking but it seems kinda dumb. If I plot some 4-dimensional surface to represent the solutions to these equations, there are definite values of k and q for any value of A and B, but for some particular value of A and B, all values of k and q are allowed. Doesn't this seem counterintuitive?

Comment: @Tachyon209 When you have a usual relationship like $y = x^3$, for any $y$ there is a corresponding value of $x$ but $x$ can really take on any value. Why is it any different?

Comment: @Tachyon209 Keywords: integral, absolute value, wave function, square, value 1

Comment: Is there a proper theory in mathematics to deal with such systems where we have n linear equations and more than n variables?

Comment: @Tachyon209 These are not $n$ linear equations! Since the unknowns $k$ and $q$ are inside the exponential function, the system is fully non-linear.

Comment: Oh damn. I forgot that. Sorry. I meant general equations. Not linear. My mistake.

Comment: @Tachyon209 i guess that depends on the equations :) hard to make a theory out of things without assumptions... if they were linear, you would use Linear Algebra, but here it is not so simple. One general idea is what I used here, so successively use equations one by one to eliminate the variables.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for your help.